# Media Creation - What's an Alternative Terminology for X & Y Axis?

Tags: gui-design, terminology

I'm creating an online media editor and am struggling to find alternate/correct terminology for aligning something (media) on the X-axis & Y-axis, or maybe these terms are understandable for users?

Options for X-Axis: Left/Center/Right
Options for Y-Axis: Top/Center/Bottom

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X and Y can be taken as Horizontal and Vertical Alignment respectively.

Alternatively, you may implement a preview with a dynamic example output. This will allow users to toy around and get an idea of what they want. I personally do not know what other options for X and Y really do besides "center", at (0,0), and I'd assume all other options are either maybe "maximum" for up/top left/right or arbitrarily defined.

Comment: I like the preview idea, but I'd take it a step further and let this be the primary input mechanism as well. Providing a 3x3 grid of boxes could quickly answer both questions with a single click, allowing the user to simply select the relative position while not having to interpret the terminology at all.

Comment: Thank you both for your guidance. I currently have a dynamic example beside (cannot share), but making it the primary input mechanism is a great idea! Even vertical and horizontal alignment terminology is much better than what I had previously. Very much appreciated, thank you.